# Unable to get flow variable inside exception-strategy

Tags: exception, mule, esb, rollback

Unable to get flow variable inside exception. In below code I am trying to use centirofilename inside default-exception-strategy. It gives Exception

```
<set-variable value="#[xpath('//soap/filename/text()').text]"
variableName="centirofilename" doc:name="Variable" />

<default-exception-strategy>
  <rollback-transaction exception-pattern="*" /> <!-- [1] -->
    <processor-chain>
      <logger level="INFO" category="ProTSP Logger"
              message="#[centirofilename]" doc:name="Logger" />
    </processor-chain>
</default-exception-strategy>
```

Comment: Try with this code  inside rollback in logger component #[flowVars.centirofilename]  or #[flowVars['centirofilename']]

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `rollback-exception-strategy` instead of the one you're using. The exception strategy you're using is legacy and it's use is not recommended.